# Symlink command in Dockerfile doesn't create the link in the container

Tags: docker, symlink

In my Dockerfile I have this line:

`RUN ln -s /var/www/html/some_file /var/www/html/another_file`

When running docker build all the steps are executed including the creation of the symbolic link, but when I start a container using the image created and check the folder `/var/www/html/` I don't see the link there.
I tried searching online if this is something supported by docker and couldn't find an answer.
The content of the container is already available by another container image I am using with the `FROM` instruction, so the file `/var/www/html/some_file` is not on my machine.

No Volumes are involved. This is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM piwik:3.2.1-apache

RUN apt update

RUN ln -s /var/www/html/some_file /var/www/html/another_file

CMD [ "apache2-foreground" ]
```

Comment: Are volumes involved at all, either through a Dockerfile `VOLUME` instruction, a `docker run -v` option, or a Compose `volumes:` block?  Can you edit the question to include a [mcve] including in particular the base image you're using and the command you're using to look for the symlink in the container?

Comment: Edited the question with my Dockerfile. and no volumes are involved at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Dockerfile for that image](https://github.com/matomo-org/docker/blob/334185afd9977d3896c02e942d093eebe11d79c9/apache/Dockerfile) (three and a half years old and not getting any updates!) has the line:

```
VOLUME /var/www/html
```

This will prevent any subsequent RUN instructions from making any changes to that directory, even if it's in a derived image.

There's no way to un-VOLUME a directory, so if you need this symlink to exist, you either need to create a new image from a base PHP image installing the software yourself, or wrap its entrypoint script with your own that creates the symlink at startup time.